# A glitch: 10 notifications or +10 rep?

Tags: bug, top-bar

I ran into a funny bug: my iPhone was resting with the Stack Exchange page opened (puzzling) for about 10 minutes (screen on), when I glanced and saw 10 unread notifications.

“That’s strange” - thought I, considering that it has not been even 15 minutes since my last visit. “Someone must have spammed comments under some post” - thought I.

However, I checked my notifications and nothing new was here:

[image]

After a page reload it appeared that I had +10 rep:

[image]

The upvote, which had shown up on the screenshot above, was cast 19:45 UTC (per my reputation tab), while I was checking the page 19:53 UTC. At that time an upvote was already present, which excludes the possibility of the upvote appearing upon the page reload (having that said, it should have definitely appear on the first screenshot in this case). Also, as I mentioned, I was away not for a long time, so I barely could receive exactly 10 notifications and then have the sources of these notifications removed (what a suspicious coincidence!).

I have never seen such a behavior and that’s the first time I encountered it. It could be a bug with sockets / sockets keeping alive.

---

iPhone 12 Pro Max, iOS 15.4 
Browser: Safari

Comment: Could've been that the comments have been deleted in the meanwhile. That doesn't clear your notification counter, but does clear the messages from your inbox.

Comment: @Luuklag small note: according to the timestamp, the upvote which gave me +10 was already present when I saw the glitch, I mean it didn’t appear at the same time I reloaded the page. And of course, I can’t exclude the possibility of 10 removed comments, but for me it looks to be a coincidence with a recent upvote